# angular $state.go with param to parent state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router

I want to navigate to a child state but need to pass param to a parent state.

E.g My config :

```
$stateProvider
                .state('app', {
                    url: "/app",
                    abstract:true,
                    templateUrl: "tpl/app.html"
                })
                .state('app.loggedin', {
                    url: "/{cUserIndex:[0-9]{1,4}}",
                    templateUrl: "tpl/home.html",
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                })
                .state('app.loggedin.dashboard',{
                    url : "/dashboard",
                    controller : "tempCtrl",
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/loggedin/index.html'
                })
```

When I am navigating to :

> $state.go("app.loggedin", {cUserIndex: 1});

My URL is  :

> ## /app/1

but I want dashboard state to load by default , where my URL should be :

> ## /app/1/dashboard

How I cal load app.loggedin.dashboard state where loggedin should have stateParam passed. Something like

> $state.go("app.loggedin.dashboard", {cUserIndex: 1}); *cUserIndex should be passed in app.loggedin and not app.loggedin.dashboard state*

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [URLRouterProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider). Something like

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/app/[0-9]{1,4}', '/app/[0-9]{1,4}/dashboard')
```

Comment: Thanks for this trick but I don't want to keep any dependency on url as later I may keep url blank for every state and application should be manageable by state only

Comment: Correct statement by using URLRouterProvider is : 

`$urlRouterProvider.when('/app/:cUserIndex', '/app/:cUserIndex/dashboard');`